# Scene doesn't show move handle tool axis for my selected object

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have 2D objects in my 2D project. I select one of them, the unity3d scene does not show the X and Y axis. It only shows the boundingbox of my selected object as following:

[image]

Comment: [2nd tutorial of UI elements on Unity official website.....](https://unity3d.com/fr/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/ui/rect-transform?playlist=17111)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your Object is a UI Object and you are in RectTransform mode since UI Objects use the RectTransform instead of just Transform.

This is your current mode:

[image]

Switch to Move mode and you see will see the move handler:

[image]

You can learn more about Unity menu [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PositioningGameObjects.html).